# How to use textfield to set IP in socket

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets

I have a Socket's program, which was originally in this program are pre-written programs IP inside，now the code below:

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)@"ip address", port, &readStream, &writeStream);
```

this can only be a fixed IP address,if I want to change the use of textfield input IP.
I have two `viewcontroller` are `socketView` and `setViewcontroller`, `textfield` is placed `setViewcontroller`, `socketview` process is the use of the socket.
The value of the `textfield` into `NSString`:

```
NSString *ip = TxtIP.text;
```

My idea is to define a `NSString *dstIP` in `socketView.m`

```
NSString *dstAddress; 
-(void) initNetworkCommunication{
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)dstAddress, 8080, &readStream, &writeStream);
inputStream = ( NSInputStream *)CFBridgingRelease(readStream);
outputStream = ( NSOutputStream *) CFBridgingRelease(writeStream);

[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];

[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];}
```

Then `setviewcontrolle.m` inside to set `dstIP = TxtIP.text`.
But I know this is not directly set, how can I modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a method to solve my problem！
I use `NSUserDefaults` to store`textfield` value ：

```
NSString *IPaddress = [textfield text];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:IPaddress forKey:@"IPaddress"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Then`SocketView` to read：

```
NSString *dstAddress;
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *IPaddress = [defaults objectForKey:@"IPaddress"];
dstAddress=IPaddress;
```